# How to auto hide ribbon but only for a specific workbook and only for one worksheet in that workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How to auto hide ribbon but only for a specific workbook and only for one worksheet in that workbook when workbook opens?

When I use the below code is working as expected and hide the ribbon but when I open another excel files the ribbon in the files is also hidden.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
 End Sub
```

Comment: What about showing the ribbon again from the workbook deactivate event? You may just have to place your logic in multiple places.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added the code to Workbook_Deactivate and Workbook_Activate and it sort of working, however when I started opening multiple sheets it losing its sequence. I am definitely on the right path :D

Comment: yeah, sounds like it. You just gotta work through the scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the worksheet in a unique way e.g."aaa" and then write inside the `ThisWorkbook` module the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "aaa" Then
        'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)" 'code to hide ribbon.
    Else
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)" 'code to show ribbon.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)" 'code to show ribbon.
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "aaa" Then
        'Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)" 'code to hide ribbon.
    Else
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)" 'code to show ribbon.
    End If
End Sub
```

which is tested in Excel 2007 and Excel 2010 and works fine.

By the way, having tested `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"` in Excel 2007 and Excel 2010, throws an error, which version do you use?

If you prefer, replace the above 'hide/show lines', with those that work in your version according to the comments.

Comment: It is working but still incorrectly, some sheets hide ribbons some not and when opening another excel files the autohide is on. I am out of option and cannot find a logic.  There must be an option to lock Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon" to a specific cell. I have tried many options with Workbook_Sheetdeactivate etc. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey dimitris, The above provided is working. Thank you very much for your help. Tested on the newest version of Excel. You are the legend!